# perl regex remove newlines in string

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace

I have a Perl script which runs over a database dump in a plain text file, trying to remove all instances of newlines and possibly other odd characters when I see strings between quotes:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ( "... these are the lines I'm interested in." )
```

I slurp in the file:

```
@file = <FILE>;
```

and:

```
foreach my $line (@file) {
    $line =~ s/"[^"]*(\R)+[^"]*"//g;
    # I want to get rid of newlines in strings
    # And other odd characters I might come across
}
```

One character class I used instead of (\R) was:

```
([\r\n\t\v\f]+)
```

and I would try to:

```
$line =~ s/"[^"]+?([\r\n\t\v\f]+)[^"]*"//g;
```

I'm sure I'm missing something.  I try to start matching with a literal double quote, scan past anything not a double quote (non-greedy, at least one match), reach the characters I want to get rid of, and keep scanning not double quote (any number of other characters not a double quote) until I reach the ending double quote.

So I wanted to replace $1 capture above with nothing.

I've tried on-line regex builders, and

```
/"[^"]*?([\r\n\t\f\v]+)[^"]*"/
```

worked with an on-line test, using a short paragraph with newlines and tabs in it, although it was in PHP pcre mode.  I thought it would have worked with Perl.

Perhaps I'm not escaping some characters properly in the regex for Perl?  Or the pattern is just not going to work the way I want it to, because it's wrong.

Thank you, any help appreciated.

The regex at regex101.com:

```
"[^"]*?([\r\n\f\t\v]+)[^"]*?"
```

matches for strings like this:

"This is

my\t    test

string.

So there!"

I'm thoroughly puzzled now. :)

Comment: Isn't `\R` just any linebreak? Also, between quotes there could be non-consecutive newlines, etc.. Another problem is the quotes, are they balanced within the full input? You don't seem to be anchoring the start with any literal's.

Comment: Yes, \R is any line break I believe.  I've seen a few here searching. I think there could be non-consecutive newlines and other characters I want to replace with nothing, or just a space character. How would I anchor the start?  You mean something like"," or ", " that I expect to see before the quoted string, and maybe "," or ")" after the quoted string?  Thanks.

Comment: You slurped the file into an array and then loop over the data line-by-line but your regex indicates that you want match a multi line string.  That's not going to work.  You'll probably want/need to slurp the file into a scalar.

Comment: Try `use Data::Dumper;` and `print \@lines`. I think this will highlight one of your problems. It's defaulting to splitting on linefeeds, so each element of `@lines` is by definition a single line.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that you will only find one group of `\R`'s when there could be many groups between quotes. The best thing to do is make a callback (eval) with a general match between quotes, then substitute the `\R`'s in
the replacement.

something like:

```
sub repl {
  my ($content) = _@;
  $content =~ s/\R+//g;
  return $content;
}

$input =~ s/"([^"]*)"/ repl($1) /ge;
```

**edit**:  If you're looking for only 1 linebreak cluster, you have to
exclude linebreaks leading up to it.  For example: `[^"\r\n]+`

*edit2:* To slurp the file into `$input`, do a

```
$/ = undef;
my $input = <$fh>;
```

Comment: Not totally sure on the eval form though `s///eg`